# Graphviz draws boxes containing unicode codepoints instead of letters

Tags: graphviz

Here is the code:

```
digraph G {
  graph [layout="dot",rankdir="LR"];
  "0" [label="",shape="doubleoctagon",width=1.00,style="filled"] ;
"6" [label="",shape="doublecircle",width=0.87,style="filled"] ;
"5" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.50,style="filled"] ;
"4" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.50,style="filled"] ;
"3" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.50,style="filled"] ;
"2" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.50,style="filled"] ;
"11" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.50,style="filled"] ;
"14" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.50,style="filled"] ;
"13" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.50,style="filled"] ;
"10" [label="",shape="doublecircle",width=0.87,style="filled"] ;
"9" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.87,style="filled"] ;
"8" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.87,style="filled"] ;
"7" [label="",shape="circle",width=0.87,style="filled"] ;
"1" [label="",shape="circle",width=1.00,style="filled"] ;
  "0" -> "1" [label="t",penwidth=4] ;
"5" -> "6" [label="t",penwidth=1] ;
"4" -> "5" [label="h",penwidth=1] ;
"3" -> "4" [label="g",penwidth=1] ;
"2" -> "3" [label="u",penwidth=1] ;
"11" -> "6" [label="s",penwidth=1] ;
"14" -> "6" [label="g",penwidth=1] ;
"13" -> "14" [label="n",penwidth=1] ;
"10" -> "11" [label="e",penwidth=1] ;
"10" -> "13" [label="i",penwidth=1] ;
"9" -> "10" [label="h",penwidth=3] ;
"8" -> "9" [label="c",penwidth=3] ;
"7" -> "8" [label="a",penwidth=3] ;
"1" -> "2" [label="a",penwidth=1] ;
"1" -> "7" [label="e",penwidth=3] ;
}
```

and here is the result (notice the labels, which should have been plain letters):[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I obtain real letters as labels instead of squares containing Unicode codepoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are missing some required fonts (https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1560)
The fix will be OS & distro-specific.
To learn a bit more about what dot is/is not doing "font-wise", use the command line **dot -v myfile.gv ...**
Your graph was produced correctly for me (I know, big deal):
[image]

Comment: I got the message `fontname: "Times-Roman" resolved to: (ps:pango  Times,  REGULAR) (PangoCairoCoreTextFont) "Times 14"` which does not seem to indicate any font absence to me... How can I ask for a different font?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding  `graph [fontname = "helvetica"];
 node [fontname = "helvetica"];
 edge [fontname = "helvetica"];`